# Merging two sorted linked list--understanding why it's O(1) vs. O(N) space complexity

Tags: data-structures, merge, linked-list, big-o, space-complexity

The majority of implementations I've seen for merging two sorted linked lists iteratively are as follows.

> Create a dummy node. Point it to the linked list head that has the smaller value. Move that head to its next node. Move dummy pointer to its next node. Repeat.

I don't understand why this procedure has space complexity of O(1) and not O(N)? While we are pointing the dummy node to existing nodes in two linked lists, we're essentially creating a new linked list-- one that interweaves the two existing lists. Consequently, doesn't this still require O(N) space? The dummy node is the head of its own linked list that is separate from the original two linked lists, even though it uses the same nodes...

Comment: Pay attention to what specifically you are measuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely right that you are going to need Θ(n) storage space to hold the result of merging two lists of total length n. But how much of that storage space was already there before the function started running, and how much of that storage space is new? You already had two lists of n total elements, so you already were using Θ(n) space before you started this algorithm, and when you're done you have the same lists lying around, just rewired so that the next pointers might be pointing to different places. As a result, the *amount of memory you needed to allocate* for this procedure is not Θ(n), but rather Θ(1).

More generally, it's common when measuring space complexity to ignore the space used by the inputs to the problem, because in some sense that space cost is unavoidable and there's nothing you can do to eliminate it.

One piece of advice going forward: if you write something like O(1) or O(n), it's often a good idea to make clear whether you're measuring time or space. For example, it's clearer to say that the procedure needs *O(n) memory* or *O(1) time* rather than to say that the procedure "is" O(n) or "is" O(1), since it's unclear what you're measuring with the big-O notation when you do that.

Comment: I see. So we're taking existing pointers off of existing nodes, and pointing them elsewhere. So the original two linked lists are permanently altered. In order to preserve their state but also create a merged list, we would need additional O(N) space correct?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up with templatetypedef's answer, since the same nodes are being used for both the input and the output, there's no additional space used there.

A dummy node is only needed in languages that don't support a pointer to pointer and/or to simplify the code. In the case of C / C++ you could use something like this:

```
NODE *merge(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2){
    NODE *pDst = NULL;            // ptr to destination (merged) list
    NODE *ppDst = &pDst;          // ptr to pDst or some next pointer
    // ...
        *ppDst = ...              // add a node to the destination list
        // ...
        ppDst = &((*ppDst)->next) // advance ppDst
    // ...
    return pDst;                  // return ptr to merged list
}
```